# Bootstrap 3.0 align navbar and logo to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a logo on the right side on a navbar (code below)
How can I get the navbar to align to the bottom of the row, rather than stick to the top? The logo has a higher height than the navbar and therefore sets the height of the row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10" id="nav-left">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tws-navbar-top">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top">
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-top-item">HOME</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"  id="nav-right">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="image" alt="logo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFoddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I think .nav > li has a padding. You have to change that in order to get the alignment you want.

Comment: bootstrap [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) has different markup. I am not sure why you are using logo and navbar in a row. [Play](http://bootply.com/new) here with your markup. and if you still not succeeded. edit your question and update it with what you tried and the height and width of the logo image.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `margin-top` to your `.navbar-header` DIV.

The value of the margin is equal to the height of your logo minus 50px that is the default navbar height in Bootstrap.

```
.navbar-header {
    margin-top: 20px !important; //if the logo has a 70px height.
  }
```

Example [here on bootply](http://bootply.com/109136).